# Footer become smaller than original size

Tags: html, css

hay, I  got many problems when the dateline of the assignment around the corner. I got a problem when my footer becomes smaller than the original size after I insert new content. I try many coding to solve it. I want a state design of the footer like that but the footer became smaller. i hope i can get an answer very soon.

```css
.content{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}

.contact-wrap{
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact-in{
    padding: 40px 30px;
}

.contact-in:nth-child(1)
{
    flex: 30%;
    background: url("../img/9.jpeg");
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.contact-in:nth-child(2)
{
    flex: 45%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(240deg, white, rgb(245, 133, 152), gold);
}

.contact-in:nth-child(3)
{
    flex: 25%;
    padding: 0;
}

.contact-in h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb(151, 6, 30);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-in h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.contact-in h2 i {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: pink;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;

}

.contact-in p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-in ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.contact-in ul li{
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.contact-in ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(221, 46, 75);
    border-radius: 50px;
 }

 .contact-in ul li a i{
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 30px;
   color: #000;
 }

 .contact-in form
 {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
 }

 .contact-in-input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: transparent ;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
}

.contact-in-input::placeholder{
   
    color: white;
    
}

.contact-in-textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: transparent ;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.contact-in-textarea::placeholder{
   
    color: white;
    
}

.content-in-btn{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.contact-in iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
  

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .contact-in:nth-child(1)
{
    flex: 50%;
    
}

.contact-in:nth-child(2)
{
    flex: 50%;
    
}

.contact-in:nth-child(3)
{
    flex: 100%;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:360px) {
    .contact-in:nth-child(1)
{
    flex: 50%;
    
}

.contact-in:nth-child(2)
{
    flex: 50%;
    
}

.contact-in:nth-child(3)
{
    flex: 100%;
}
}

.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

        <div class="contact-wrap">
            <div class="contact-in">
                <h1>CONTACT INFO</h1>
                <h2><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact</h2>
                <p>03-2287 0380</p>

                <h2><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Operation Hours</h2>
                <p>Monday - Saturday : 10 am - 7pm & Sunday : 10 am - 2pm</p>

                <h2><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>Address</h2>
                <p>16-1, Jalan Telawi 2, Bangsar, 59100 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur</p>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

                
            </div>

            <div class="contact-in">
                <h1>Feedback</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="contact-in-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="contact-in-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="contact-in-input">
                    <textarea placeholder="Message" class="contact-in-textarea"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="content-in-btn">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-in">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d127482.66722752716!2d101.6169483838224!3d3.1386749714748494!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31cc49c701efeae7%3A0xf4d98e5b2f1c287d!2sKuala%20Lumpur%2C%20Federal%20Territory%20of%20Kuala%20Lumpur!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smy!4v1610039278384!5m2!1sen!2smy" 
                width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="footer">
        <p>  Copyright &COPY; 2020 | SENERITY CALLS BEAUTY SPA.CO</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: By 'becoming smaller' do you mean the height or the width gets smaller? Also can you give us example/image of the change in size when you insert new content?